# Count similarities MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have been trying to figure out a query and it goes likes this:

I have a table ingredient containing information about ingredients:

```
table ingredient
id int pk
name varchar(50)
```

I have a table category, every ingredient can have one or more category connected to it, for example ice cream could be related to the categories dessert, cold dish and so on. So a many to many relation.

```
table category
id int pk
name varchar(50)

table category_ingredient
category_id int
ingredient_id int
```

Lets say i want to make a query about how similar two ingredients are by measuring the categories they share. What I mean is, lets say my database contains 3 ingredients: 1,2,3. Ingredient 1 is connected to categories {1,2,3}, ingredient 2 is connected to categories {3,4,5} and ingredient 3 is connected to categories {1,2,3,4}.

Doing the query where I would search for the ingredients most similar to ingredient 1, would result in:

```
 Ingredient 3 100%
 Ingredient 2 33%
```

Any thought on how this kind of query would be achieved?

Comment: Why Would `ingredient 3` be 100% similar to `ingredient 1`? I think that is incorrect as whatif an ingredient **A** has categories `1` and ingredient **B** has categories `1,2,3`, this means that B is 100% similar to A when infact it's at best 33%, because B has extra categories that don't feature in A's search.

Comment: To apply the above logic to your example given in the question, ingredient 3 is **not** 100% but instead 75% because ingredient 3 features one category (of four total) which ingredient 1 does not appear in.

Comment: @Martin I think he simply wants to know what percentage of one ingredient's categories are _also_ present in another ingredient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "nice" way (in my mind) to do this query would be to use conditional aggregation involving a `CASE WHEN ... IN` expression, but MySQL does not seem to support this.  Instead, I do a cross join on the first ingredient against the entire `category_ingredient` table and count the number of categories which are in common, for each ingredient.  This number, divided by the total number of categories in the first ingredient, yields the percentage in common.

```
SELECT t2.ingredient_id,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN t1.category_id = t2.category_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category_ingredient WHERE ingredient_id = 1) AS commonCount
FROM category_ingredient t1
INNER JOIN category_ingredient t2
    ON t1.ingredient_id = 1
GROUP BY t2.ingredient_id
```

Comment: Have you tested this query?

Comment: Oh cool, took a little time to figure out what exactly it did - neat! Thanks!